# Why some user can't download the lastest app when I has update a new version to google play store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have update a new version to the google play store, and it has published, but some users feedback that they can't update to the latest version, because in there google play store, my app is still a  old version.

My guess is that whether the google play store has cache, if has, how long the cache will be updated?

Or any another reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the following FAQ? It's probably just normal lag if you're within this window.

[https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en#:~:text=All%20app%20changes%20need%20to,your%20app%20is%20subject%20to](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en#:%7E:text=All%20app%20changes%20need%20to,your%20app%20is%20subject%20to).

> **Planning for reviews and submitting updates**
>
> All app changes need to be processed before they can be published.
> **Processing can take a few hours or up to 7 days** (or longer in
> exceptional cases), as it depends on the review time that your app is
> subject to. Tip: We recommend that you adjust your planning to include
> a buffer period of at least a week between submitting your app and
> going live.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons, the common ones are

1. Play Store Caching: However, an app update is reviewed and published play store app might cache previous data and might not show the update available immediately it will be visible after a few hours.
2. Roll-out percentage: You can specify a percentage of users to which the new update has to be shown. There is a chance of having it 20% by default. Hence the app update will be visible to 20% of your users.

These are common causes that lead to such an issue. Do verify these are proper in your case